# Image upload error in Laravel api, when accessed from another computer in LAN

Tags: php, api, laravel

We have made an API in Laravel, which resgisters a new user with user info and an image. While testing this API with postman, it works fine locally. But when this API is accessed from another computer in LAN, it throws 500 internal server error. Also all other API endpoints are working fine and register API also works fine if we remove the image.

What's the reason behind this strange behaviour?

Comment: You could try posting the culprit code, we can't guess how your API works

Comment: seems like it was the issue with upload folder's permission. Thanks, its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was the issue with permission in upload directory. We changed the permission of the upload directory and everything seems to work flawlessly now. I hope this answer might help someone out there someday :)

Comment: Please indicate that this answer should be the accepted answer since you solved your problem :)